# What certificate is needed to connect to firebaseio.com?

Tags: firebase, rest, security, certificate

I have written my own code to connect to Firebase via the REST interface.  Recently I have been unable to connect to firebaseio.com because the secure connection cannot be established with the CA certificate I am using.

I am still able to create a secure connection to googleapis.com to handle the login authentication and get the tokens I need for communication.

How do you determine what certificate is needed to validate the connection?  I have tried a few of the root CA certs available at https://pki.goog/repository/ but they do not seem to work for firebaseio.com.

Answer (score 0):

WireShark to the rescue!  I was able to see the name of the certificates being passed to my device.  Firebaseio.com is using one of the certs in [this list](https://pki.goog/repository/) that I had not tried yet.

After adding that one I was able to connect.  How often does Firebase change these certificates?  What is the proper method to keep my device up to date with the latest certificates?